# SED - "Filename too long" - is there a way to skip this error?

Tags: linux, sed

I am running this command:

```
cd /tmp;find / -maxdepth 2 -type f | xargs -0 sed -i 's/teststring1/finally/g'
```

It processes until it comes to a point where it reports an error: file name too long. Looking up the docs, it seems like it is when there is a file name longer than 1024 bytes. Anyway, I thought using print 0 would supress this, but no.  Are there any commands to skip errors rather than just stop?

Comment: You could pipe to `while read line` instead of xargs? That way it will skip the failed lines and continue with the others.

Comment: I couldn't get the syntax right, could you show me the command in the context of mine mate?

Comment: Did you re-type this command by hand? The `cd /tmp; find /` is a bit funny, and there's no `-print0` in the command despite there being a `-0` in the `xargs(1)` command line. Please don't re-type commands or code, it makes debugging far harder for no good reason. Copy and paste please. :)

Comment: I'm having trouble reproducing this; on my `ext3` `/tmp` directory, file and directory names can't be longer than 256 chars, and when I place a file seven directories lower, it's still not giving the _filename too long_ error message.

Answer (score 3):

```
cd /tmp;
find / -maxdepth 2 -type f -exec sed -i 's/teststring1/finally/g' {} \;
```

The `{}` will be changed to each filename, and works even for files with spaces in their names.

Comment: Better yet, `-exec sed ... {} +`.