# SED - "Filename too long" on a variable

Tags: ubuntu, sed, terminal

i am trying to modify a json stored in a variable like this:

PS: (This error was kinda covered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9404891/sed-filename-too-long-is-there-a-way-to-skip-this-error) also but I tried the same process which makes terminal quit).

```
#The variable has some information about a json file (around 10 keys).
infos = [{"id":512,"hostName":"PC-1","pcModel":"Dell","diskType":"Samsung:...}]
#I want to modify the key where "Win10" is written and replace it with "Ubuntu" like this
sed -i "s/Win10/Ubuntu/g" "$infos"
#Then I get the error
bash: /bin/sed: Argument list too long
```

Is there a way to avoid this error with sed?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed and parallel):

```
parallel sed -i 's/Win10/Ubuntu/g' {} ::: $infos
```

Will edit files in place and in parallel.